# how to wait for a result of a http request (syncronous http request, http request as promise)

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I have a typescript service that loads base data by htpp requests from a server. There are several requests for several data, arranged in order from undependent data to data depending on data, for which loading ist started bevor. Because the asynchronous http requests it is not guaranteed, that loading data by a request (e. g. customers in the following example) has finished, bevor loading the data that depends on it starts (e. g. devices in the following example) and i can not refer on loading devices to loaded customers. But i would like, that laoding the dependent data (devices) starts, after loading the data refereing to (customers) has finished. I think i need to use promises, but how to implement concrete in the following code situation?

```
export class BaseDataService
{
  customers: Customer[] = new Array();
  devices: Device[] = new Array();

  // Loads the base data arranged in order from undependent data to data dependent data  
  loadBaseData() {
    this.loadCustomers();
    // this operation should be started after loading customers has finished (the response json 
    //is parsed to an array of customers at set to the instance variable of this service class)
    this.loadDevices();
  }

  // Loads the customers and adds them to the collection of customers.
  // Also puts the response json string of the customers to the local storage.
  loadCustomers() {
    console.log("Load customers");

    var requestURL = 'https://myurl/kunden_json_user_extern.php';
    var auth = window.localStorage.getItem('auth');
    var requestparam = "auth="+auth;

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', requestURL);
    request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(requestparam);

    request.onload = () => {
      if (request.status === 200){ 
        console.log("Load customers response");
        // gets as json string with the customers array
        var response = request.response;
        // parses the json string of customers to an array of customers objects
        this.customers = this.parseCustomers(response);         
        console.log("Load customers complete");
    }
    else if (request.status === 401){
      alert("unautorized");              
    }
    else {
      // lade saved items aus local storage
      alert("unerwarteter Fehler");
    }
  }
}

// Loads the devices and adds them to the collection of devices.
// Also puts the response json string of the devices to the local storage.
loadDevices() {
  console.log("Load devices");

  var requestURL = 'https://myurl/geraete_json_user_extern.php';
  var auth = window.localStorage.getItem('auth');
  var requestparam = "auth="+auth;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', requestURL);
  request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.send(requestparam);

  request.onload = () => {
    if (request.status === 200){ 
      console.log("Load devices response");
      var response = request.response;          
      window.localStorage.setItem('devicesresponse', response);
      this.devices = this.parseDevices(response);          
      console.log("Load devices complete");
    }
    else if (request.status === 401){
      alert("unautorized");              
    }
    else {
      // lade saved items aus local storage
      alert("unerwarteter Fehler");
    }
  }
}


// Parses a json string formatted like the response of customers to an array of customers
parseCustomers(customersjson: string)
{
  let customerarray = JSON.parse(customersjson);
  let customers: Customer[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < customerarray.length; i++) {
      let customer: Customer = new Customer();
      customer.setId(customerarray[i]['id']);
      customer.setName(customerarray[i]['name']);
      customer.setPlace(customerarray[i]['ort']);
      customer.setStreet(customerarray[i]['strasse']);

      customers[i] = customer;
  }
  return customers;
}

 // Parses a json string formatted like the response of devices to an array of devices
 parseDevices(devicesjson: string)
 {
   let devicearray = JSON.parse(devicesjson);
   let devices: Device[] = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < devicearray.length; i++) {
      let device = new Device();
      device.setId(devicearray[i]['geraet_id']);
      device.setSerialnumber(devicearray[i]['geraet_seriennummer']);
      device.setDescription(devicearray[i]['geraet_bezeichnung']);
      // here i would like to refer to a prevoiusly loaded customer
      //device.setCustomer(this.baseDataService.getCustomer(devicearray[i]['geraet_kunde_id']); 
      device.setLocation(devicearray[i]['geraet_standort']);

      devices[i] = device;
     }
    return devices;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use something like axios, which wraps that in a promise for you?

Comment: Please stop using 20 year old functions. Use fetch instead

Comment: Answer of your problem is to use async / await

Comment: Let me know if my synchronous ajax call answer worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback to any of 'load' functions, so:

This code:

```js
loadBaseData() {
    this.loadCustomers();
    // this operation should be started after loading customers has finished (the response json 
    //is parsed to an array of customers at set to the instance variable of this service class)
    this.loadDevices();
  }
```

Change to this code:

```js
loadBaseData() {
    this.loadCustomers(() => {
        this.loadDevices();
    });
  }
```

And call this callback inside your `request.onload`:

```js
// Loads the customers and adds them to the collection of customers.
// Also puts the response json string of the customers to the local storage.
loadCustomers(callback) { // <--- this is a callback passed to function
    // ... many code here ...
    request.onload = () => {
        // ... many code here ...
        console.log("Load customers complete");
        if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(); // <--- here we call it
    }
// ... many code here ...
```

Comment: I think passing callback would not be good. this is only an excerpt and there would be many data more loaded, passing a callback to a load function, to whoch is passed a callback and so on would lead to call hell.

Comment: making an synchronous call xhr.open(""post, url, false) works thanks

Comment: i know, using fetch and async / await would be the nicest and state of the art solutiion. but am am very new to javascript ans do not understand the promise usage. How would i have to implement it with using a promise and async / await

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `synchronous ajax` call like below. So it waits for the response before executing the next statements.

```
xhr.open("POST",url,false);
```